# How to break a 'while' loop

Tags: python-3.6

I want to end the program after the user has entered Y. I put break
after the print, but it doesn't break the loop and still goes back to
input. How do I break the loop?

```
while True:
        exit_input = input("Are you sure you want to exit? Enter Y/N (YES/NO): ")
        if (exit_input == 'Y'):
            print("\nYou have successfully exited the program. Thank you! Have a great day! ")
            break
        elif (exit_input == 'N'):
            run = menu()
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid Input\n")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: Sorry, its still not working. I have tried other ways as mentioned in the other post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have entered does work. Make sure that you enter an uppercase Y. Not a lowercase, as it is case sensitive.